# How do I populate an unordered list one element at a time with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to populate an unordered list with values that have been entered into a text field. When I press the submit button, I want to push the value in the field into the first item on the list. After entering another value, the most recent entry becomes the first item of the list, and older entries move down the list. In other words, the entries should stack on top of pervious ones on the list.

## HTML

```
<div id="previous">
    <ul id="previous-list">
        <li class="previous"></li>
        <li class="previous"></li>
        <li class="previous"></li>
        <li class="previous"></li>
        <li class="previous"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Prepend the new items to the ul element

Comment: tada -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2D7Lf/1/**

Comment: I like the use of object notation rather than a string of HTML, thats a new one for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `prepend` method like this

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('ul').prepend('<li>new</li>');
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vL6Gn/